# Coded UI - Another control is blocking the control

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing, coded-ui-tests

I'm new to Coded UI automation testing. In my MVVM silvelight application, doing automation testing for HyperlinkLink button and facing below error (see image):

[image]

Stack Trace:

at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.Engine.IScreenElement.MouseButtonClick(Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 nButton, Int32 fEnsureVisible, String bstrKeyModifiers)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.MouseButtonClick(Int32 x, Int32 y, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Int32 ensureVisible)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.MouseButtonClick(Int32 x, Int32 y, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.Click(MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Point relativeCoordinates)

Error Message:
Another control is blocking the control. Please make the blocked control visible and retry the action. Additional Details: 
TechnologyName: 'Silverlight'
ControlType: 'Image'
Source: '../Assets/Images/add.pn

Please Help..!!

Comment: In your code you are specifying coordinates for the control. Did u try removing the coordinates and then trying?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when there is a transparent control overlaid on the control you are trying to click - First, make sure that no other windows are covering what you're trying to work with and then you can do the (slightly less reliable) version of Mouse.Click() which clicks on a point on the screen instead of clicking on the control. To do so, pass in a Point to the .Click method -

```
Mouse.Click(uIAssertsImagesaddpngImage.GetClickablePoint());
```

The downside to doing this is that if there is actually another window or control over top of the button you're trying to click, you're going to end up clicking on it instead. That's where the loss of reliability comes in.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Mouse.Hover()` to demonstrate access to the control, and then `Mouse.MoveScrollWheel()` to move the location of the control to a place where it can be manipulated.

Background:
This is the first internet result on SO for `FailedToPerformActionOnBlockedControlException` that involves browser automation (as opposed to a desktop application) so I'm going to add my solution here. It does not involve Silverlight, but I'm not certain that matters.

For me, I would attempt to manipulate an element on the page, but that element was "below" the screen. Using any number of CodedUI methods that are supposed to grab the control (like `.SetFocus()`) would grab the appropriate control. However it would bring the control to the bottom part of the screen, where a semi-transparent bar across the bottom of the screen would block the control. Wanting to adjust where the control would be displayed on the screen, I attempted to use `Mouse.MoveScrollWheel()`, but the mouse action would not occur. Using `Keyboard.SendKeys("{PGDN}")` would not work either since CodedUI focus was "trapped" in a control. This particular application uses three browser windows (not tabs) open simultaneously, so mouse focus never made it onto the screen without something to trigger it. I eventually got around all of this using the following code

```
System.Drawing.Point location = obj.BoundingRectangle.Location;
Mouse.Hover(location);
Mouse.MoveScrollWheel(-2);
```